# Mockito: how to mock doAnswer for a generic method

Tags: java, generics, lambda, mockito

I have a class that, in essence, looks like this:

```java
class Checkpointer {
  public <Input,Output> Output runFunction(Input input, Function<Input,Output> function) {
    Output output;
    // Sometimes run the function, sometimes return an Output from a cache
    return output
  }
}
```

I would like to mock this class using Mockito `doAnswer`:

```java
Checkpointer checkpointer; // mocked via @Mock annotation

Mockito
  .doAnswer(/* ??? */)
  .when(checkpointer)
  .runFunction(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
```

The function I want to mock needs to be generic. Can this be done?

For example, my first attempt produced the following. Not only did I resort to `Object` as the type arguments for `Function`, but the compiler was still unhappy with unchecked casting:

```java
Mockito.doAnswer((invocation) ->
        {
            // compiler is not happy with this cast   V
            Function<Object,Object> function = (Function<Object,Object>)invocation.getArguments()[1]; 
            return function.apply(invocation.getArgument(0));
        }).when(checkpointer).runFunction(Mockito.any(), Mockito.any());
```

If this can't be done, I think can try writing my own mock class extending the first and use `Mockito.spy`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you insist on using `getArguments`, which returns an `Object[]`
Since you **know** the index of the `Function` argument, you can use `getArgument(index)`, as you're doing the line after that.

```
final Function<String, String> argument = invocation.getArgument(1);
```

Is this what you're looking for? Type inference for the `getArgument` generic type is working fine.

If not, can you provide a more elaborate example?

Comment: Thank you for the response - your answer addresses the compiler warning, but not the `Function<Object,Object>` hack. However, as `Function<Object,Object>` **works**, I think your response gives me an acceptable answer.

Comment: @GordonBean what do you mean with "but not the Function<Object,Object> hack"?  You can use whatever types you want with that.

Comment: My point is that the checkpointer method expects an argument of `Function<Input,Output>` - so the type `Function<Object,Object>` isn't 100% accurate. Thus, the `doAnswer` lambda is only guaranteed to return an `Object`, even though the method it is mocking claims to return something of generic type `Output`.

Comment: @GordonBean the thing is when you are testing you know exactly which type of objects you'll deal with. So the "generic" problem is a non-problem imho

Comment: within a given invocation of the calling function, the `runFunction` method will be called multiple times with different types. So I can't mock the function once with one set of type args. I guess I could use arg matchers to switch on input type and setup a `doAnswer` for each expected input type.